# nuget update -self error

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

Running `nuget update -self` from VS 2017 Developer Command Prompt I encountered the following error. How do I make nuget upgrade itself to the latest version?

[image: Nuget update error]
Checking for updates from https://nuget.org/api/v2/.

Currently running NuGet.exe 2.0.30619.9000.

Updating NuGet.exe to 4.4.1.

The element 'metadata' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd' has invalid child element 'developmentDependency' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'title, tags, summary, licenseUrl, releaseNotes, copyright, description, projectUrl, frameworkAssemblies, language, references, dependencies, iconUrl' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd'.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make nuget upgrade itself to the latest version?

You can run the command `nuget update -self` from VS 2017 Developer Command Prompt without following error:

> 'nuget' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

That means that you should added a path of `nuget.exe` to the environment variable before or you have a old nuget.exe under the path `C:\Users\bboyl\Source`.

If you want to update nuget itself, you could **manually** download the the newer version form [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/downloads), Under the section titled "**Windows x86 Commandline**", replace the old version in the path on your PC.

BTW, It seems the nuget.exe version `2.0.30619.9000` of the system environment variable path is too low to automatically update. So we have to update it **manually**, just download the new version of `nuget.exe`.

For example, I have a nuget.exe with version `4.1.0.2450` under the path `D:\NuGet4.0`, then I set this path into the environment variable. After that, I could update the `nuget.exe` itself to `4.4.1` in the VS 2017 Developer Command Prompt:

[image]

Now we could also update nuget itself with the command `nuget update -self`.